# How to obtain row with a column name that exists in two tables which is not unique?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `vendors` and `customers`, with the following fields:

**vendors:**

```
vendor_id         name                  UUID
---------    --------------          ---------------
1               V1 vendor               01ffd02
2               V2 vendor               02daaa2
3               V3 vendor               41ddasa
```

**customer:**

```
customer_id         name                  UUID
---------    --------------          ---------------
1               cust1                  71ffd02
2               cust2                  92daaa2
3               cust3                  11ddasa
```

The UUIDs above are not foreign keys, and not unique for both the tables.

I have to write a single query to capture all rows *in either table* with a given UUID. For example, if `UUID = '11ddasa'`, the result should be the last row in `customer` above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT name,UUID from vendors where UUID='11ddasa'
UNION
SELECT name,UUID from customer where UUID='11ddasa'
```

This will return all rows from either table with UUID.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    vendors
WHERE   uuid = '11ddasa'
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    customers
WHERE   uuid = '11ddasa'
```